# Modify mysql tables creating 1 new

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for not many clear title.

1st table "place":

```
ID     PLACE      AREA_1     AREA_2    AREA_3
1      Mago         23         45        67
2      Gelato       23         45        12
```

And so on

2nd table "area_1"

```
ID    ID_AREA_1    AREA_1
1       23         Lazio
```

3rd table "area_2"

```
ID    ID_AREA_2    AREA_2
1      45           Roma
```

4th table "area_3"

```
ID    ID_AREA_3      AREA_3
1        12            Roma
2        67            Velletri
```

Of course with 3 `INNER JOIN` I can extract in this mode

```
ID    PLACE     AREA_1_NAME       AREA_2_NAME      AREA_3_NAME
1     Mago      Lazio             Roma             Velletri
```

But I need to re-factory the database, losing 2nd, 3rd and 4th table and I need to obtain a new, unique table directly with

```
ID    PLACE     AREA_1_NAME       AREA_2_NAME      AREA_3_NAME
1     Mago      Lazio             Roma             Velletri
```

1) I need absolutely to mantain inalterate the ID (id of place) of the 1st table (are used in others tables that I will mantain)

2) I don't need anymore the 2nd, 3rd and 4th tables

Could you help me to create the SQL statement for MySQL to prattically move the result of the JOINS to a new table?

Thank you very, very much!

Comment: And why doesn't `create table as` work with the query that has three inner joins?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know **CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT [...]) :)**